# Flexslider in google map info window is not loading images

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, flexslider, infowindow

I am trying to add a slider in a django app in google maps infowindow using flex slider. My code is this.

```
{% load thumbnail i18n humanize static %}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#slide1 , #slide2').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    slideshow: false,
    controlNav : false,
    start: function(slider) {
  slider.removeClass('loading');
}
  });

});
</script>




<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var markers=[];
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("gmap"),  {
    zoom: 5,
    minZoom: 2,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    panControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false
});
{% for course in courses %}
    {% if course.object.location %}
        var lat = '{{ course.object.location.lat }}';
        var lng = '{{ course.object.location.lng }}';
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            draggable:true,
            title: '{{ course.object.location }}'
        });

        var course_detail="<div class='flexslider loading custom_space_remove' id='slide1'><ul class='slides'><li class='relative'><a class='family-member' href='{{course.object.get_absolute_url}}'>{% thumbnail course.object.image '1000' as im %}<img src='{{ im.url }}'/>{% endthumbnail %}</a></li>{% for image in course.object.course_images.all %}<li class='relative'><a href='{{course.object.get_absolute_url}}'>{% thumbnail image.image '1000x749' crop='center' as im %}<img src='{{ im.url }}'/>{% endthumbnail %}</a></li>{% endfor %}</ul></div>"

         makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, course_detail, marker);


        bounds.extend(marker.position);
        markers.push(marker);
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

function makeInfoWindowEvent(map, infowindow, contentString, marker) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    }

map.fitBounds(bounds);
});
</script>
```

It is working fine except loading the images. When i click on a google map marker it shows me info window with complete html but on the place of images it shows me only 'ajax loading image/ function', means images are not loaded using this code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this applies here, but in Android infowindows are [NOT a live view](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#custom_info_windows). From what you've said it sounds like the infowindow is stuck showing loading. Perhaps you can refresh your infowindow by opening/closing it or setting content again.

Answer (score 0):

Add domready to marker

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, "domready", function() {
  $('#slider').anythingSlider();  });
```